# R View not working after using another View

Tags: r, view

When I use the following code in R to see my NA, no problem:

```
na_count <-sapply(MyData, function(y) sum(is.na(y)))
MyData$Numerator<-rownames(na_count)
View(na_count)
```

It's when I go back to the following code:

```
View(MyData)
```

The column Numerator is missing.  Could someone tell me how to get back all my original columns?  Thank you for your help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead of `rownames` only `names` to get the desired result. `Sapply` returns a named vector and no data frame. And a vector does not have row names.

Comment: Thank you, it works when I changed it to "names".  I can now pull up all my original data.